# Codeigniter How to pass value from view to view to update DB record

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, controller

i have table here

```
 <?php     if ( !empty($kirim) ) 
                      {  
                            $no = 1;   
                            foreach ($kirim as $row) { ?>  
                            <tr id="row">  
                             <td id="no"><?php echo $no;?></td>  
                             <td id="judul"><?php echo $row->Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa;?></td>  
                             <td id="kategori"><?php echo $row->Nama_Material_Jasa;?></td>  
                             <td id="action"> Edit | Delete </td>
                         //idk how to pass the value for updating
                        //and using YES or NO DialogResult for deleting
                            </tr>  
                            <?php  
                             $no++;  
                            }  
                     } 
                     else { ?>  
            <tr id="row">  
            <td colspan="6" align="center">Tabel Kosong</td>  
            </tr>  
        <?php  
        }  
        ?>
```

and i want to pass the `Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa` and `Nama_Material_Jasa` to another form, so we can update the values there, and update the DB record. i have made the form and i confuse to pass the value direct to the update form. or pass them to the controller, then pass it again to the update form.

i was adding some code here

```
<td id="action"> <a href="<?php echo site_url('/c_kategorimaterial/ubah/').$row->Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa/$row->Nama_Material_Jasa; ?> ">Edit </a>| Delete </td>
```

then i got error like `Division by zero`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would do it is using either POST or GET (depending how sensible is your data).

Using GET:

```
<td id="action"> <a href="<?php echo(site_url('/c_kategorimaterial/ubah/').$row->Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa."/".$row->Nama_Material_Jasa; ?> ">Edit </a>| Delete </td>
```

Notice you missed `."/".` between the first and the second time you echo  `$row->Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa`

Using POST

1. Define a field in your form like:

   ```
   <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo ($row->Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa);?>" value="<?php echo($row->Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa);?>">
   ```
2. Retrieve the value in the destination controller (the one you set in you `action=URL` in the form tag) by using `$_POST`

Comment: how do i do that post method on table ? cz i got table like this 
`id | name |
id001 | name1
id002 | name2|`

how do i do hide on id field ?

Answer (score 3):

Is better to pass it to the controller in this way:    myController/myFunction/Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa/Nama_Material_Jasa and then pass it to the view containing the form.

Comment: there's controller called `c_kategorimaterial` and it has `edit()` function, so, i need to open `c_kategorimaterial/edit/Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa/Nama_Material_Jasa` and then fill the `edit()` to load views `edit_form` ?

Answer (score 0):

I would keep DB functions inside your *model* and use the *controller* to pass them to your *views* as this is how this system is build. [(MVC and Codeigniter)](http://phpmaster.com/untangling-mvc-with-codeigniter/)
I strongly advice against what you are doing now.

Here's how I think it should be done:

- Send your view data trough your controller, validate it [(as documented here)](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html)
- Store the data in the database via your model
- Pass this data to and load your next view